# `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection` from running BRugsFit()

Tags: r

I have a error about `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection` from running BRugsFit(). I assume all the input arguments are fine, and the calling code is

```
> output = BRugsFit("model.txt", data, inits, numChains = 2, seed=6, parametersToSave,nBurnin = 100,nIter = 1000, nThin = 5, coda = T,digits = 5)

****
* BlackBox
* string too long
- HostFiles.Init  (pc=00003FB1, fp=BFFDE550)
- HostFiles.$$  (pc=0000000A, fp=BFFDE560)
****
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/tmp/RtmpU7v9PZ/buffer.txt': No such file or directory
```

So I wonder what might be the reason of the error, and how to solve it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It tells you that the file `model.txt` doesn't exist. Try to indicate the full path to the file:

```
output <- BRugsFit("/path/to/file/model.txt", data, inits, numChains = 2, seed=6, parametersToSave,nBurnin = 100,nIter = 1000, nThin = 5, coda = T,digits = 5)
```

or first set the working directory with `setwd`:

```
setwd("/path/to/file/")
```

Comment: It seems like that my working path is too long. Is there a restriction from BRugsFit?

Comment: Too long? I wouldn't think that's the problem. No idea about BRugsFit

Comment: Window limits the length (number of characters allowed) in a file path. If BRugsFit writes a file, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when trying to write to a temporary directory, it looks like the above is the same problem. The directory is made, but the file cannot be written to that directory despite changing permissions. The working directory, the path to the file I am working with, and the path to the temporary directory are all fine. It looks like the OP is having the same conflict.

EDIT: I fixed this problem by changing the extension on the file. Although both extensions referred to the same file type, the code would only take one of them.    |    Sometimes closing the console/terminal and restarting it, loading the libraries again on start-up is all it needs. (presumably would work for the GUI without saving or using prior workspace)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if I have spaces in a directory name (and/or dashes), R gives me the same errors (at least on OSX).

e.g. when the directory is '.../.../.../blah blah blah - blah' it does not work.

Renaming the folder to e.g. '.../.../.../blah_blah_blah-blah' resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is because shiny create a new folder (outside .rproj file) that contain app.R file. Hence I need to move my css file to the same folder, or I specify the path folder which is less convenient